# How to package node js console application to an executable

Tags: javascript, node.js, executable

I have a console like application in node js , and i want to package it for window's executable .

My project is setup is regular :

```
app.js
node_moudles
bin
readme.md
support file
support file
package.json
```

Both support files are generated when the program is run first time .

 Another detail , some of my dependencies are native applications(I'm using electron).

Is there a packaging solution , as i want to distribute **only** a exe that will have a node js instance as well as all my modules ?

Comment: *A simple solution that may not be the best, you have to create a bat file that runs you node app.js. this bat file can easily be converted to windows exe using free tools such as 
[battoexeconverter](http://www.battoexeconverter.com/)* - as said by [oussamalachiheb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2144797/oussamalachiheb)

Comment: I'm looking to a packaging solution to also include my node_modules , as I only want to publish one exec file

Answer (score 2):

Electron itself can be built as .exe. Wouldn't make sense to pack it again. However when you have projects with non-native code use [nexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe).

Comment: Well , I'm not using electron directly , I'm using nightmare js to automate some browser things , but it uses electron , hence why I have the bin folder. How should I pack it then ?

Comment: Nightmare is for testing. So if you don't need in "production" you can go with nexe.

Comment: Actually my whole code is around nightmare , and I don't use it as testing

Comment: Then I guess you can only use `npm shrinkwrap`. Should be fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since i didnt find anything that can pack node js project with native dependencies into one exe file the workaround i found is to disctibute the node.js code with a package.js , and that the user will run `npm install` first , before using the package.